# is include path changing by folder for PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php file in my application root. I can access it like this: `localhost/auth.php`

My **auth.php** is here.

```
include_once("infrastructure/account/AccountManager.php");

if(AccountManager::isUserLoggedIn()){
    echo '{"user":{"isAuthenticated": true"} }';
}else{
    echo '{"user":{"isAuthenticated": false} }';
}
```

I want to put auth.php in a user folder in the root. `localhost/user/auth.php`
And I moved **auth.php** to **user** folder. But warning occured.

**include_once(): Failed opening 'infrastructure/account/AccountManager.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')**

is **include_once** relative path changing by file location?

Comment: `include_once('../infrastructure...')`. Because your `auth.php` went down a folder, your include path changes.

Comment: What exactly do you think the meaning of the word “relative” is, hm?

Comment: Once the path isn't absolute (so doesn't start with `/`), then it will relate on _current working directory_. That may be not the directory of current script (in case if it's included), it's the directory from which script trace execution has begun. It may be changed with `cd` somewhere inside the script, but in common situation - it will be script startup directory

Answer (score 0):

The base for he relative path is taken always as the current working directory.

So, as when you change the location of auth.php to "user" folder the executing directory changes to "user" folder.

You have to go to the root folder to select the folders from root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
include_once("localhost/infrastructure/account/AccountManager.php");
```

or

```
include_once("../infrastructure/account/AccountManager.php");
```

../ refers to the parent directory of the current directory; if you need to go back two levels you have to use ../../ and so on.

Comment: this works but this time, the other files that referenced in "/infrastructure/account" are giving warning.

Comment: Since you moved auth.php to another folder all the files that auth.php points to and all the files that point to auth.php could output errors  so you need to check and modify them where required.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/infrastructure/account/AccountManager.php");
```